# C lang: Turbo C, DOS, Input = 4. Output =$ $$ $$$ $$$$. Going infinite loop for char input. S

Tags: c, turbo-c

User gives input and accordingly the pattern must be printed. It should encounter negative numbers and char as input. I encounterd the negative value as input but as I try to give char input it goes on ifinite loop. So how can I encounter char value for int data type as an input.

````c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
/*
C program to print the pattern allowing user
to input the no. of lines.
*/

//Declaring method for printing pattern
void printPattern(int numberOfLines);

void main()
{
    char userChoice;//User's choice to continue or exit
    int numberOfLines;//User's input for number line to be printed

    clrscr();

    //Logic for printing the pattern
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the number of lines you want to print \n");
        scanf("%d",&numberOfLines);

        //Countering issue if user enters a char insted of number
        /*while()
        {
            printf("Enter number only \n");
            scanf(" %c",&numberOfLines);
        }*/

        //Countering issue if user enters negative number
        while(numberOfLines<=0)
        {
            printf("Enter positive number \n");
            scanf("%d",&numberOfLines);
        }

        //Calling method to the start printing of method
        printPattern(numberOfLines);

        //Taking user's choice to continue or not
        printf("Press Y to continue else any other key to exit \n");
        scanf(" %c",&userChoice);
    }
    while(userChoice == 'y' || userChoice == 'Y');
}

/*
Method  definition for printing the pattern
Argument numberOfLines: User's input for number of lines
*/
void printPattern(int numberOfLines)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0 ; i<numberOfLines ; i++) //for rows
    {
        for(j=0 ; j<=i  ; j++) //for columns
        {
            printf("$");
        }
        printf("\n"); //for going to next row after printing one
    }
}```
````

Comment: Tag spam removed. Lets try and stay on target, shall we ?

Comment: Input to be taken in `string` and convert to integer.

Comment: Why are you reading the parameter from stdin?  Take it from argv instead.  Don't use scanf until you have more experience.

Comment: Egads @Wackie [10 Commandments for C Programmers -- NO. 6](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html). You fail to validate any (*any*) of the user-input and therefore tempt *Undefined Behavior* by proceeding to process the input without ever knowing whether valid input was received. Bad Juju...

Comment: What's `argv`? @William Pursell

Comment: @Wackle `argv` is the conventional name for the second argument passed to `main`.  It is the list of strings passed on the command line.

Comment: regarding: `void main()`   There are only two valid signatures for the function: `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Notice they both have a return type of `int`, NOT `void`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `scanf("%d",&numberOfLines);` you want to read an integer. If you then enter a letter, like an `a`, nothing will be read from the input stream. In other words, you'll go into an endless loop where you keep trying to read an integer but the stream contains a letter.

You need to remove that letter from the stream.

You could try:

```
while(scanf("%d",&numberOfLines) != 1)
{
    // Didn't get an integer so remove a char
    getchar();
}
```

However, that will lead to problems if the input stream fails.

The better solution is to use `fgets` and `sscanf`

Comment: Thanks for the solution brother. Can you please explain the meaning of `while(scanf("%d",&numberOfLines) != 1)` in detail. Because the code worked but I don't know the meaning of this condition in the while loop

Comment: @Wackie The function `scanf` returns the number of elements successfully matched. So if 1 integer is matched (and stored in `numberOfLines`) the function returns 1. So in that case you have `while(1 != 1)` which is false and therefore stops the loop. But if no integer is matched `scanf` will return 0 and you have: `while(0 != 1)` which is true and the loop will continue. So all together it means that the loop will continue until you have matched an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter, simpler version of `printPattern`

```
void printPattern(int n)
{
    char dollar[n];
    memset(dollar, '$', n);

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        printf("%.*s\n", i, dollar);
}
```